# Reason for filter(admin_approved=True,valid_from__lte=now, valid_to__gte=now) not working immediately?

Tags: python, django

I have a project where there are posts that I want to be displayed for a certain period of time `valid_from` and `valid_to`

so the issue here is that I have added the correct filters and choosen the time but the posts keep displaying although the time `valid_to` has passed. I was in doubt until I added a countdown which became negative and exceeded the time `valid_to` value.

I am trying to understand the reason behind this issue and how to fix it?
here is the models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    valid_from = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    valid_to = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is the veiws:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post.html"
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    now = timezone.now()
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(valid_from__lte=now, valid_to__gte=now)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`now` will *not* update, it will simply take the value when the class is interpreted for the first time and then *reuse* that value every time.

You can override the [**`get_queryset(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset), but perhaps more elegant is using the [**`Now()`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#now) of the database:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(
        valid_from__lte=Now(),
        valid_to__gte=Now()
    )
```

This will use the database time instead.

If you want to override the `get_queryset(…)` method instead, you write:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        now = timezone.now()
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            valid_from__lte=now,
            valid_to__gte=now
        )
```